# Combine where clause

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I need to filter out value from two column with combine two condition 
If level in (101,102) and Hiredate = current month will be eliminate 
This is my script

```js
 SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME, LEVEL, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE
FROM Table
WHERE
  (LEVEL in ('101','102') and month(ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE) != MONTH(GETDATE()) and YEAR(ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE) != YEAR(GETDATE())) and ACTIVE > 0 and LOCATION_CODE = '1030' 
   order by LEVEL asc
```

As script result is all level 101,102 is eliminated but thing i want is level 101,102 and hiredate not equal current month

Exampledata

[image]

Desire result

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Ok i have just edited example data and desire result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a not at the beginning of the where clause and change those != from =

```
create table #t1 (level int, original_hire_date date);
insert into #t1 values(101,'2019-09-19');
insert into #t1 values(102,'2019-09-19');
insert into #t1 values(103,'2019-09-19');
insert into #t1 values(104,'2019-09-19');
insert into #t1 values(200,'2019-09-19');
insert into #t1 values(101,'2018-9-11');

select *
from #t1
where not (level in ('101','102') and month(original_hire_date)=month(getdate()) and year(original_hire_date)=year(getdate()))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Your script very short i think your script better then my scripts

Answer (score 0):

you can use `format()` if your `sql server` is `2012` higher.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME, LEVEL, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE
FROM Table
WHERE
    (LEVEL not in ('101','102')  and ACTIVE > 0 and LOCATION_CODE = '1030' 
UNION ALL
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME, LEVEL, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE
FROM Table
WHERE
    (LEVEL  in ('101','102') and (LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE,112),6) != LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(),112),6))
    and ACTIVE > 0 and LOCATION_CODE = '1030'
```

or you can use `OR` operator

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME, LEVEL, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE
FROM Table
WHERE
  (LEVEL not in ('101','102') 
  OR
  (LEVEL in ('101','102') and (LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE,112),6) != LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(),112),6)))
    and ACTIVE > 0 and LOCATION_CODE = '1030'
```

Comment: i faced "FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name"

Comment: try the 2nd query

Comment: Thank you it works but my objective is filter out some value

Comment: based on your desired output it should be `not in ('101','102') `

Comment: Yes i think so but i need 101,102 have hiredate not equal current month

Comment: this one is what you need `UNION ALL` or `OR`

Answer (score 0):

I might use `EOMONTH()` for the current date.  This would result in:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, LEVEL, ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE
FROM Table
WHERE LEVEL NOT (101, 102) AND
      EOMONTH(ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE) <> EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND
      ACTIVE > 0 AND
      LOCATION_CODE = 1030 
ORDER BY LEVEL ASC;
```

I removed the single quotes from `101`, `102`, and `1030`.  The values look like numbers, so I assume they are.  Only use single quotes if the values are strings (or dates).

Comment: i faced " EOMONTH' is not a recognized built-in function name"

Comment: @WD_Apps . . . `EOMONTH()`is available in every supported version of SQL Server:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 0):

Now i use + two columns then compare it works but i am not sure about performance and correct way